# how to call this attribute from a class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been trying to call an attribute of that class but I get an Typeerror, I wanna get namepilot from pilot and print it

This is my    **Pilot.ts**

```
namespace tsprojectnamespace {
import Vehicle = tsprojectnamespace.Vehicle;
import Pilotinterface = tsprojectnamespace.PilotInterface
export class Pilot implements Pilotinterface {
    private vec: Vehicle;
    public _namepilot: string;
    private _agepilot: number;

    constructor(name, age,vec: Vehicle) {
        this.vec = vec;
        this._agepilot = age;
        this._namepilot = name;
    }

    get namepilot(): string {
        return this._namepilot;
    }

    set namepilot(value: string) {
        this._namepilot = value;
    }

    get agepilot(): number {
        return this._agepilot;
    }

    set agepilot(value: number) {
        this._agepilot = value;
    }

    driving() {
        return this.vec.driving();
    }
}
}
```

This is my class    **Car.ts** , this class inherits from another class vehicle

```
namespace tsprojectnamespace {
import TypeVehicleInterface = tsprojectnamespace.TypeVehicleInterface;
import PilotInterface = tsprojectnamespace.PilotInterface;
export class Car extends Vehicle implements TypeVehicleInterface, PilotInterface {
    private _pilot : Pilot;
    private _brand: string;
    private _model: string;
    private _torque: number;
    constructor(brand, model, torque, weight, speed, pow) {
        super(weight, speed, pow);
        this._brand = brand;
        this._model = model;
        this._torque = torque;
    }

    get pilot(): tsprojectnamespace.Pilot {
        return this._pilot;
    }

    set pilot(value: tsprojectnamespace.Pilot) {
        this._pilot = value;
    }

    get brand(): string {
        return this._brand;
    }

    set brand(value: string) {
        this._brand = value;
    }

    get model(): string {
        return this._model;
    }

    set model(value: string) {
        this._model = value;
    }

    get torque(): number {
        return this._torque;
    }

    set torque(value: number) {
        this._torque = value;
    }

    drive() {
        return `the car's model is ${this.brand} ${this.model}`;
    }

    driving() {
        return `the pilot ${this.pilot.namepilot} is driving the Car ${this.brand} ${this.model}`;
    }
}
}
```

I mean, Car.ts return a function with basic info about the car, this is the console's output without getting the namepilot

```
the pilot is driving the Car Lamborghini egoista
the pilot is driving the Car Ferrari sergio
the pilot is driving the ship
the pilot is driving the ship
The pilot is planning the Plane
The pilot is planning the Plane

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is what I wanna get

```
the pilot 'lewis' is driving the Car Lamborghini egoista
the pilot 'ferdinand'is driving the Car Ferrari sergio
the pilot "" is driving the ship
the pilot "" is driving the ship
The pilot "" is planning the Plane
The pilot "" is planning the Plane
```

and this is what I got

```
        return "the pilot " + this.pilot.namepilot + " is driving the Car " + this.brand + " " + this.model;
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'namepilot' of undefined
at Car.driving (C:\Users\Downloads\ts project\final.js:163:45)
at Pilot.driving (C:\Users\Downloads\ts project\final.js:78:29)
at Function.doActions.pushElements (C:\Users\Downloads\ts project\final.js:298:32)
at tsprojectnamespace (C:\Users\Downloads\ts project\final.js:331:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Downloads\ts project\final.js:333:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What should I do?

***UPDATE***

I already have 2 more classes extending vehicle like ship and plane

I forgot to put my test variables

```
        let pilot1 = new Pilot(`lewis`, 50, new Car(`Lamborghini`, `egoista`, 1200, 1300, 360, 650));
        let pilot2 = new Pilot(`ferdinand`, 34, new Car(`Ferrari`, `sergio`, 900, 1200, 320, 750));

        pilots.push(pilot2, pilot1);
        console.log(pilot1.driving());
        console.log(pilot2.driving());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that the Car object is never told who is driving it.

You could update the Pilot constructor as such:

```
 constructor(name, age,vec: Vehicle) {
     this.vec = vec;
     vec.pilot = this;
     this._agepilot = age;
     this._namepilot = name;
 }
```

That way your Pilot object would assign itself to the car it is driving upon instantiation.

**Edit**

Alternatively, if altering the implementation of the classes is not an option, you could change the way you instantiate your objects:

```
// Instantiate the cars 
let lamborghini = new Car(`Lamborghini`, `egoista`, 1200, 1300, 360, 650);
let ferrari = new Car(`Ferrari`, `sergio`, 900, 1200, 320, 750);

// Instantiate the pilots
let pilot1 = new Pilot(`lewis`, 50, lamborghini);
let pilot2 = new Pilot(`ferdinand`, 34, ferrari);

// Link the pilots to their respective car
lamborghini.pilot = pilot1;
ferrari.pilot = pilot2;
```

As a side note, it might be worth considering rewriting the Pilot class or the Car class a bit. This second solution is predicated on our knowledge of how the Pilot and Car classes are implemented, which is not ideal.

At the very least, if there's a possibility that the `Car.driving()` method will be called under conditions that prevent it from executing properly, then there should be some validation around that.

Comment: your answer it was there, I required to modify my abstract class Vehicle and that's what I least wanted, is there a way to do this without modifying that kind of classes, cuz I'm trying to follow the SOLID principles

Comment: I've updated the answer with an alternative solution. Let me if this is closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: not too much, but it works, I found a way and it was declaring pilot as protected, it was just 1 line more of code

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've attributed your pilot to your car first?

```
myCar.pilot = pilotHamilton;
```

You omitted a part of the testing code, so we don't really know  if the pilot variable of your instanciated Car class is set somewhere in your testing class.